# jQueryUI autocomplete CSS suggestion list width

Tags: css, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've just rewritten this question rather than tell a shaggy dog story.

Using `position : relative` and `z-index` on the `ui-autocomplete` class and by letting `autocomplete()` append the suggestion box to the default element, I have my suggestions popping up underneath the text input and overlaying the controls that appear beneath it in the form.

The problem is the width.  How do I get it to take its width from the `input`?  At the moment, it takes up the whole page width.

Here's my CSS:

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    position : relative;
    z-index : 50;
    list-style : none;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: solid 1px lightblue;
    text-align : left;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    max-height : 100px;
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 0px;
}

.ui-menu 
{
    text-decoration : none;
    white-space : nowrap;
}

li.ui-menu-item a
{
    color : gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    display : block;
    white-space : nowrap;
}

li.ui-menu-item a:hover
{
  background-color : lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People looking for definitive answers on CSS, try css-tricks.com.  It was here I got the rules of positioning and sizing spelled out to me in a way that gave me the confidence to make a change, knowing what I expected it to do and see it work!

The answer to this particular problem was that the width was defaulting to 100%.  If you add `float`, the width adjusts to the contents of the box.

So:

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    float : left; 
    clear : both; /* make sure it doesn't pull the next line up next to it */
    position : relative;  /* z-index will not work without this */
    z-index : 50;
    list-style : none;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: solid 1px lightblue;
    text-align : left;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    max-height : 100px;
    margin : 0px; /* pull the list items over the left edge */
    padding : 0px;
}
```

And that's it. Hope it saved you the 2 days of googling I just burned on it :-)